# Dominated Convergence Theorem - Royden's proof

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

In Royden's proof, he states

> We infer from Proposition 15 that, by possibly excising from $E$ a countable collections of sets of measure zero and using countable additivity of Lebesgue , measure, we may assume that $f$ and each $f_n$  is finite on $E$.

My confusion is that I don't see how $f$ and $f_n$ are finite on $E$. I only see that they are finite a.e on $E$. Furthermore, finiteness a.e on $E$ is enough for the rest of the proof to go through.

[image]

Comment: If $f$ is finite a.e on $E$, that means there is a measurable subset $N\subset E$ such that for every $x\in E\setminus N$, we have $|f(x)|<\infty$. Now, simply consider $\tilde{f}(x)= f(x)$ if $x\in E\setminus N$ and $0$ otherwise. Then, $\tilde{f}$ is still measurable, and $\int_E\tilde{f}\,d\mu = \int_Ef\,d\mu$. So, we really don't lose any generality. Ok, and you can do this for $f,f_1,f_2,\dots$, so we get sets $N,N_1,N_2,\dots$; but the countable union $\tilde{N}=N\cup\bigcup_{j=1}^nN_j$ will still have measure zero, so everything works out. But you're right, a.e is good enough for Fatou.

Comment: Yes, I agree but still $\tilde{f}\neq f$ in your argument. I understand $f$ is finite a.e on $E$ is needed for the proof to go through. My question is more about why $f$ is assumed to be finite on $E$ or is it just bad use of language?

Comment: When the author says "we may assume..." what this means is that if the theorem is true for $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{f}_n$ (in my notation above), then the theorem is true for $f$ and $f_n$ (the author has omitted a proof of this simple implication of course). The author leaves it to you to prove this implication, and he goes on to prove the theorem for $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{f}_n$. Yes, you're right that $\tilde{f}\neq f$ pointwise, but all we care about is that their integrals are equal.

Comment: Thanks. Now that makes sense.

Comment: @peek-a-boo if you collect thses comments into an answer then I will accept it.